# Can I create a docker-compose.yaml that only creates networks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a set of docker-compose files that create services, and custom networks. Some of the compose files refer to networks in others.

eg.:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  (...)


volumes:
  (...)

networks:
  management:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0.10 
    ipam:
      config:    
      - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
  home:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.3.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.3.1
```

This compose file create a couple of services and two networks.

Now I have another compose file that uses one of these networks as well, and creates another one of their own:

```
version: '3'
services:
  (...)

networks:
  home:
    external:
      name:               my_other_service_home
  iot:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0.12
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.12.0/24
```

For the sake of clarity I would prefer to create all the networks in a separate file. And then just refer to them by name as external networks in the other compose files.

But this did not work:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  iot:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0.12
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.12.0/24
  management:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0.10
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
  home:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.3.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.3.1
```

The file was accepted without error, but I just got the message that the networks were not used, and therefore not created.

Is there a better aproach?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a dummy service in your `networks.yml` file, that does not do anything and exits immediately?

Something along these lines:

#### Create the networks

```
# networks.yml
services:
  dummy:
    image: alpine
    networks: [hello, sky]

networks:
  sky:
    name: skynet

  hello:
    name: hellonet
```

#### Create the service(s)

```
# service.yml
services:
  service:
    image: alpine
    networks: [sky]

networks:
  sky:
    external:
      name: skynet
```

#### Execute

```
$ docker-compose -f networks.yml up
$ docker-compose -f service.yml up
```